# Error al dar click en botón ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Tengo un problema con un botón en Flutter, ya que al presionarlo no genera ningún evento, y no se me ocurre alguna forma de solucionarlo.

Este es mi código:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fbutton/fbutton.dart';
import 'package:quiz_cisco1_0/quizprincipal.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyAppState());


class MyAppState extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Cisco Quiz",
      home: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar:  true,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Image.asset("assets/cisco_logo.png", width: 200, height: 200,),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Image.asset("assets/quizz.png", width: 200, height: 200,),
              ),
              Text("La App Perfecta para prepararte", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              Text("en Cisco CCNA 1,2 y 3", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              SizedBox(height: 85.0),
              FButton(
                width: 185,
                height: 60,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                text: "Empezar",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20.0),
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => MyAppsds()));
                },
                clickEffect: true,
                corner: FCorner(
                  leftBottomCorner: 40,
                  leftTopCorner: 6,
                  rightTopCorner: 40,
                  rightBottomCorner: 6
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Este es el otro archivo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './quiz.dart';
import './result.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class MyAppsds extends StatefulWidget{
  _MyAppState createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyAppsds> {
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': '1. Un router con un sistema operativo válido contiene un archivo de configuración almacenado en la NVRAM. El archivo de configuración tiene una contraseña secreta de habilitación pero no una contraseña de consola. Cuando el router se inicie, ¿qué modo se mostrará?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Modo de configuración global', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Modo de ejecución privilegiado', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Modo EXEC usuario', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Modo de configuración', 'score': -2},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': ' 2.¿Por qué un switch de Capa 2 necesitaría una dirección IP?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Para permitir que el switch envíe tramas de broadcast a los PCs conectados', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Para permitir que el switch funcione como una puerta de enlace por defecto', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Para permitir que el switch reciba tramas de los PCs conectados', 'score': -2},
        {
          'text':
          'Para permitir que el switch sea administrado a distancia',
          'score': 10
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': ' 3.¿Cuál es el SVI por defecto en un switch Cisco?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'VLAN999', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'VLAN1', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'VLAN99', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'VLAN100', 'score': -2},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': '4.En el comando ‘show running-config’, ¿qué parte de la sintaxis está representada por ‘running-config’?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Una palabra clave', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'El comando', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Una variable', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Un aviso', 'score': -2},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': '5.¿Qué tipo de tráfico de red requiere QoS?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Video conferencia', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Compra en línea', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Wiki', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Correo electrónico', 'score': -2},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': '6.¿En qué capa del modelo OSI se añadiría una dirección lógica durante el encapsulamiento?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Capa física', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Capa de enlace de datos', 'score': -2},
        {'text': 'Capa de red', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Capa de transporte', 'score': -2},
      ],
    },
  ];

  var _questionIndex = 0;
  var _totalScore = 0;

  void _resetQuiz() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = 0;
      _totalScore = 0;
    });
  }

  void _answerQuestion(int score) {
    _totalScore += score;

    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(_questionIndex);
    if (_questionIndex < _questions.length) {
      print('We have more questions!');
    } else {
      print('No more questions!');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Quiz Cisco'),
          flexibleSpace: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/banner.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        body: Padding(

          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: _questionIndex < _questions.length
              ? Quiz(
            answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
            questionIndex: _questionIndex,
            questions: _questions,
          ) //Quiz
              : Result(_totalScore, _resetQuiz),
        ), //Padding
      ), //Scaffold
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ); //MaterialApp
  }
}
```

Y este es el error:

Exception caught by gesture
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Navigator.of. (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2711:9)
#1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2718:6)
#2      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2116:22)
#3      MyAppState.build. (package:quiz_cisco1_0/main.dart:37:29)
#4      _FButton.onPressed (package:fbutton/fbutton.dart:561:23)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#665d0
debugOwner: GestureDetector
state: possible
won arena
finalPosition: Offset(184.2, 566.6)
finalLocalPosition: Offset(96.7, 6.1)
button: 1
sent tap down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se da porque no tiene un widget Padre que tenga un `Navigator` incluido. Para solucionarlo tienes varias formas pero pondré la más simple y más usada:

En lugar de iniciar el app con el widget `MyAppState` usa otro widget que contenga el `Navigator` es decir usando el `MaterialApp` (que ya incluye el navigator), entonces quedaría así:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Cisco Quiz",
      home: MyAppState(),
    );
  }
}
```

Y a `MyAppState` le quitas el `MaterialApp`, queda así :

```dart
class MyAppState extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar:  true,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
```

Comment: Hermano eres el mejor!! Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: de nada :) , te invito a mi canal para que veas cosas más avanzadas de Flutter : www.youtube.com/diegoveloper